# Should I create extension, module or work in vqmode in opencart?

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

I'm going to work with Opencart system where my requirement is to read a file from sftp server( Different Location ) and take some specific filed's data from that file and update my Opencart system database. And everyday 4 times this process will run automatically which will be a cron job. As I don't have previous knowledge about Opencart, so need valuable suggestion, should I develop Opencart extension, module or should work in VQmode? Please it will be helpful for me If anyone can give me good suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends exactly what you need. The best not to use vqmod or OCMOD.

Answer (score 1):

Note. OpenCart 1.5.x workrs with **VQMOD**, OpenCart 2.1 and later - **OCMOD**. They are quite different. **OCMOD** is OC native technology. I suggest you to use OpenCart no less then 2.3, better 3.0.3.2.

**OCMOD** is used, when we need to do changes something in core files, without doing it directly. **OCMOD** - is a set of instructions, to find a file, tile a certain line(s), replace it or arr code before or after it. Use it when you need to overwrite core files.

Extensions/Modules - mostly something that you going to show on the client side of your store.

Extensions/Tools - have almost the same structure and login, as modules, but you can place it wherever you want in admin menu (using OCMOD). You can use modules or tools, there is no big difference and strict rules.

As I see your process - you will create some your own extension (model, controller and view), and some small part in **OCMOD**, to correct some core files (if necessary). Don't forget, in **OCMOD** you can't change `.css` and `.js` files. Only `.php`, `.tpl` and `.twig`. That's all I can tell you according to your question.

Comment: Do not forget, that in OC 2.3 and later exist event system. So there are a lot of possibilities do not alter core files. In another words some times it is not necessary to use OCMD just create events.